# undefined value cause my whole function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

i have defined a global javascript function in masterpage

**MasterPage**

```
<script>
if(typeof data !='undefined'){
function doSmth{
if(data[A])
//Do something
}
}
</script>
```

**Homepage**

```
<script>
var data = {
Fruit : "apple"
}
</script>
```

**Detail**

```
var data is not defined in this page
```

before i added typeof data !='undefined', everything work fine, i can call apple in homepage but just i received a javascript error from detail because data is undefined, to prevents continuing receive javascript error, i added typeof data !='undefined', but somehow whole function is not working, why this is happen?

Comment: Well we need to see how do you call that function , in what context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `MasterPage` script as

```
<script>
    function doSmth(){
        if(typeof data !== 'undefined'){
            if(data[A]){
            //Do something
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Ideally you should pass parameter to function rather than using global variable.
So I would suggest you to use

```
<script>
    function doSmth(data){
        if(typeof data !='undefined'){
            if(data[A]){
            //Do something
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And call function like

```
<script>
    var data = {
       Fruit : "apple"
    }
         doSmth(data);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your master page

```
<script>
function doSmth{
if(typeof data !='undefined' && data[A])
//Do something
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

function doSmth{
   if(data !=undefined){
      //Do something
   }
}
</script>
```